# How to combine zip files with Archive::Zip in Perl

Tags: perl, zip

I have two zip files, `A.zip` and `B.zip`. I want to add whatever files are in `A.zip` to `B.zip`.

How can I do this with [`Archive::Zip`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Archive-Zip/) in Perl? I thought I could do something like this:

```
my $zipA = Archive::Zip->new();
my $zipB = Archive::Zip->new();

die 'read error' unless ($zipA->read( 'A.zip' ) == AZ_OK );

my @members = $zipA->memberNames();
for my $m (@members) {
 my $file = $zipA->removeMember($m);
 $zipB->addMember($file);
}
```

but unless I call `writeToFileNamed()` then no files get created, and if I do call it, `B.zip` gets *overwritten* with the contents of `A.zip`.

I could read in the contents of `B.zip`, and write them along with the contents of `A.zip` back to `B.zip` but this seems really inefficient. (My problem actually involves millions of text files compressed into thousands of zip files.)

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Archive::Zip`:

```
my $zipA = Archive::Zip->new('A.zip');
my $zipB = Archive::Zip->new('B.zip');

foreach ($zipA->members) {
    $zipA->removeMember($_);
    $zipB->addMember($_);
}
$zipB->overwrite;
```

The problem is:

1. You need to add the actual members, not just the memberNames.
2. You need to read B.zip before you can add to it.

(I'll leave it to you to do error handling etc)

Comment: Is `$zipA->removeMember($_);` really needed?

Answer (score 0):

You may try [`chilkat::CkZip`](http://www.chilkatsoft.com/refdoc/perlCkZipRef.html) instead of `Archive::Zip`. Its `QuickAppend()` method seems to be helpful.